# Matching columns within the same table in SQLite

Tags: join, sqlite, self-join

I have a table of Employees which contain, among other things, the employeeId, the lastName and the ReportsTo column, that refers to the manager ID to which the employee has to report. That manager is just another employee in the same table, so there is only one employee whose value in this column is zero, which means he/she doesn't have to report to anybody.

I need to retrieve a list with the managers last name, and the last name of the employees who report to him or her.

I suspect I have to use a Self Join but I'm not sure how to write it, so any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: for example:
https://ramkedem.com/en/oracle-self-join/

Comment: *I need to retrieve a list with the managers last name, and the last name of the employees who report to him or her.* Do you want to have a record per reporter (manager can have a lot of records with different reporters) or you want to compact this into one record per manager with (CSV) list of reporters?

Comment: Each manager can have many records, I think there are just 3 managers, so what my query has to give me in the first columns is the last name of those 3 people.